# How would you form the URL to test the output of a SVC?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, svc

I have a SVC web service located at

http://localhost/myProjects/WebServices/Retriever.svc

Let's say Retriever.svc.cs has a method

```
[WebGet]
[OperationContract]
public string[] CoolMethod(string prefixText, int count)
{
.....
return some string[];
}
```

How could I form a URL in my browser to see what the output of it would be?

Can I do something along the lines of

http://localhost/myProjects/WebServices/Retriever.svc/CoolMethod?arg1?arg2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can do

http://localhost/myProjects/WebServices/Retriever.svc/CoolMethod?prefixText=box&count=5

Should have tried it before asking, but leaving it here for others to reference.

Comment: i agree with the last part of your answer: "should be here for others to reference". That's the whole point of this site.

Comment: It should be .../Retriever.svc/CoolMethod?prefixText=box&count=5 (you need the method name in the URI, and the separator for the parameters should be '&' instead of '#'